# Multiline TextInput height in Gmail Addon

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I am populating email body in a TextInput which is set to display in multi-line mode. Now since the email body is large, rest of the add-on content is obviously pushed way down the screen. In order to prevent that i decided to populate email body inside a different section and set it to collapsible. That worked great.

Now when i expand the collapsed section the multiline TextInput height is reduced to height of single line input. See attached GIF.

Anybody knows if there is a way to make to it so that it takes full height after the section is expanded or at least somehow set the height of the input? I didn't find anything in the Card Service API supporting this functionality.

This is how i created the section and text input

```
  var descriptionSection = CardService.newCardSection()
                          .setCollapsible(true)
                          .setHeader('Description');

descriptionSection.addWidget(CardService.newTextInput()
         .setFieldName("Description")
         .setMultiline(true)
         .setValue(emailParameters.body));
card.addSection(descriptionSection);
```

[image]

Comment: How about trying to set the [`setMultiline()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/text-input#setmultilinemultiline) like this `setMultiline(multiline)`. It said that it will set whether the input text **shows** on one line or multiple lines.

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 I am already setting setMultilile(true). See code above.